# PHP merge 11 arrays into one

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I am trying to combine 11 different arrays into one.
This is how my code looks so far:

```
$combine = [];
foreach($data as $key => $array){
    $combine[$key] = array_merge($array,$data1[$key],$data2[$key],$data3[$key],$data4[$key],$data5[$key],$data6[$key],$data7[$key],$data8[$key],$data9[$key],$data10[$key]);
}
```

Here are what some of the arrays look like:

`$data`

```
array(10) {
[0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["VideoName"]=>
    string(61) "TUTORIAL 1: How to Give an Awesome (PowerPoint) Presentation "
    ["1min"]=>
    string(2) "35"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["VideoName"]=>
    string(48) "TUTORIAL 2: How to open and close presentations?"
    ["1min"]=>
    string(2) "30"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["VideoName"]=>
    string(47) "TUTORIAL 3: Make a presentation like Steve Jobs"
    ["1min"]=>
    string(2) "12"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["VideoName"]=>
    string(56) "TUTORIAL 4: The five secrets of speaking with confidence"
    ["1min"]=>
    string(2) "20"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["VideoName"]=>
    string(93) "X.EXAMPLE 1 - Abraham Heifets: How can we make better medicines? Computer tools for chemistry"
    ["1min"]=>
    string(2) "24"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["VideoName"]=>
    string(70) "X.EXAMPLE 1 - Carol Dweck: The power of believing that you can improve"
    ["1min"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["VideoName"]=>
    string(66) "X.EXAMPLE 2 - Johanna Blakley: Social media and the end of gender "
    ["1min"]=>
    string(2) "15"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    ["VideoName"]=>
    string(56) "X.EXAMPLE 3 - Tim Berners-Lee: A Magna Carta for the web"
    ["1min"]=>
    string(2) "17"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(2) {
    ["VideoName"]=>
    string(57) "X.EXAMPLE 4 - Eli Pariser: Beware online "filter bubbles""
    ["1min"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(2) {
    ["VideoName"]=>
    string(103) "X.EXAMPLE 4 - Jasdeep Saggar: Hypoxia-activated pro-drugs: a novel approach for breast cancer treatment"
    ["1min"]=>
    string(2) "21"
  }
}
```

`$data5`

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["VideoName"]=>
    string(48) "TUTORIAL 2: How to open and close presentations?"
    ["6min"]=>
    string(2) "24"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["VideoName"]=>
    string(47) "TUTORIAL 3: Make a presentation like Steve Jobs"
    ["6min"]=>
    string(2) "21"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["VideoName"]=>
    string(56) "TUTORIAL 4: The five secrets of speaking with confidence"
    ["6min"]=>
    string(2) "16"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["VideoName"]=>
    string(66) "X.EXAMPLE 2 - Johanna Blakley: Social media and the end of gender "
    ["6min"]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["VideoName"]=>
    string(56) "X.EXAMPLE 3 - Tim Berners-Lee: A Magna Carta for the web"
    ["6min"]=>
    string(2) "11"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["VideoName"]=>
    string(57) "X.EXAMPLE 4 - Eli Pariser: Beware online "filter bubbles""
    ["6min"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

`$data10`

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["VideoName"]=>
    string(70) "X.EXAMPLE 1 - Carol Dweck: The power of believing that you can improve"
    ["11min"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

However when I run the code this is what I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJgxP.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMXTu.png)

It merges everything perfectly for the first video, but after that it displays null. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: without loop : `$combine = array_merge($array[0],$data[0], $data1[0],...`

Comment: Are you want the letter element of the array override the former?

Comment: Can you share your expected output as well?

Comment: I encode it into json and I expect a final output which looks something like this:  ' {"VideoName":"X.EXAMPLE 1 - Carol Dweck: The power of believing that you can improve","1min":"35","2min":"59","3min":"40","4min":"18","5min":"17","6min":"24","7min":"13","8min":"28","9min":"1","10min":"1","11min":"2"}' but for all of the 10 videos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the simple way like this,

```
$combine = [];

$datas = [];
foreach(range(1, 10) as $index)
{
  $variable = 'data' . $index;
  $datas[] = $$variable;
}

$combine = $data;
foreach($datas as $data){
  foreach($data as $key => $array;
  {
    foreach($array as $k => $v)
    {
      $combine[$key][$k] = $v;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: At first I thoght it worked but after I had a secound look at the data I found out  that the data was all wrong. I converted it to a JSON and you can see it here https://api.myjson.com/bins/yux9f . Around 4-5 videos are missing and the data for the ones that are there is all wrong. Any idea where the problem is?

Comment: What's wrong, what are you expecting at? We have asked in the question comment, and you replyed nothing.